# What About Pods in kubernetes when NFS Server down

Tags: kubernetes, nfs

I am pretty new on Kubernetes.Assume that i have 2 slave 1 master cluster and i have a nfs server.I create a pv on nfs and a pvc for a pod.What if NFS Server down? Is the pod still continue to work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No pod will fail as you created claim on pv and using it in pod.  So pod expect claim to be available. But as nfs server is down.,  pod will not find it so pod will be crashed.